# Line break from MySQL longtext to HTML via PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html, line-breaks

I have multiple lines of text entered into a single MySQL longtext cell that I would like to display in HTML. However, I cannot figure out how to keep the line break when the string is displayed in HTML.

For example, let's say I have this text in the column "content":

```
+-----------+
|  content  |
+-----------+
| Line 1.   |
|           |
| Line 2.   |
+-----------+
```

I want this to display:

```
Line 1.

Line 2.
```

However, I am getting this result with my PHP loop:

```
Line1.Line2.
```

I used the loop below to `echo` the text from my database. (I know I don't need a loop, but in the actual project I am displaying multiple rows of data).

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY timestamp DESC");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo $row['title'];
}
```

In sum: How can I maintain line breaks when displaying a MySQL string in HTML? Is there any way to add `<br>` at the line breaks?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try using php function `nl2br` ([docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php))

```
$content = "Line 1.\nLine 2.";
echo nl2br($content);
// output Line 1.<br>\nLine 2.
```